# Transforming seconds (Floats) to hours/seconds/minutes

Tags: ruby, time

I have a Float which represents seconds. So, I can have 38.93 seconds.  I am looking for the "rubiest" way to get hours if possible, or minutes if hours is not possible and if minutes and hours are not possible just seconds.  When I say possible I mean:

If there are less than 3600 seconds it will be minutes or seconds. If there are less than 60 seconds, it will be seconds.

Right now I do several if to see what should it be, but I am thinking there might have to be a cleaner way.

```
if input > 3600
   return input/3600, 'hours'
elseif input < 3600 && input > 60
   return input/60, 'minutes'
else 
   return input, 'seconds'
```

Thanks

Comment: 38.93 is not a Fixnum.

Comment: David, sorry I meant Float

Answer (score 5):

IMHO a case statement with ranges would be a bit cleaner:

```
def some_method_name(input)
  case input
  when 0...60
    input, 'seconds'
  when 60...3600
    input/60, 'minutes'
  else
    input/3600, 'hours'
  end
end
```

Another approach would be to extract hours, minutes and seconds first:

```
def some_method_name(input)
  hours, seconds = input.divmod(3600)
  minutes, seconds = seconds.divmod(60)

  if hours > 0
    hours, 'hours'
  elsif minutes > 0
    minutes, 'minutes'
  else
    seconds, 'seconds'
  end
end
```

Within Rails you would of course use the build-in [pluralization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization).

Answer (score 1):

This approach has the advantage of being able to flexibly specify the unit intervals desired.  It would be easy to add weeks, approximate months, years, if you wanted to. It also fixes pluralization for singular values.

```
TimeInt = Struct.new :name, :secs
INTERVALS = [ TimeInt[:days, 60*60*24], TimeInt[:hours, 60*60],
              TimeInt[:minutes, 60], TimeInt[:seconds, 1] ]

def time_with_adaptive_units(secs)
  ti = INTERVALS.find { |ti| secs >= ti.secs } || INTERVALS.last
  val, name = (secs.to_f/ti.secs).round, ti.name.to_s
  name.sub!(/s$/,'') if val == 1
  "#{val} #{name}"
end

[5] pry(main)> time_with_adaptive_units(1)
=> "1 second"
[6] pry(main)> time_with_adaptive_units(45)
=> "45 seconds"
[7] pry(main)> time_with_adaptive_units(450)
=> "7 minutes"
[8] pry(main)> time_with_adaptive_units(4500)
=> "1 hour"
[9] pry(main)> time_with_adaptive_units(45000)
=> "12 hours"
[10] pry(main)> time_with_adaptive_units(450000)
=> "5 days"
```

Comment: This is nice! Where should I define the Struct though? Using Rails, I wanted to put the method in the ApplicationHelper. If I define the struct inside the method itself I get a "dynamic constant assignment" error.

Comment: @HommerSmith I'd define the Struct and INTERVALS right above the method definition if this is the only place you'll use it.  It's just a little companion to make the INTERVALS data self labelling.

Answer (score 0):

There's what I could think of:

```
total_seconds = 23456
intervals = [3600, 60, 1].inject({rem: total_seconds, parts:[]}) do |memo, factor|
    count = (memo[:rem] / factor).floor
    memo[:rem] = memo[:rem] - (count * factor)
    memo[:parts] << count
    memo
end
```

And you could finish it up with

```
itervals[:parts].zip(['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']).map{|p| p.join(' ')}.join(', ')
```

You can also see that it's trivial to expand this to days, weeks, months, years, decades and centuries if you want to :D

Answer (score -1):

```
input = 4000 #input in seconds
h = {(60..3599) => ["input/60",'Minutes'], (0..59) => ["input",'Seconds'],(3600..Float::INFINITY) => ["input/3600",'Hours']}
h.each_pair {|k,v| p "#{v.last} is #{eval(v.first)}" if k.include? input}

input = 1100 #input in seconds
h = {(60..3599) => ["input/60",'Minutes'], (0..59) => ["input",'Seconds'],(3600..Float::INFINITY) => ["input/3600",'Hours']}
h.each_pair {|k,v| p "#{v.last} is #{eval(v.first)}" if k.include? input}

input = 14 #input in seconds
h = {(60..3599) => ["input/60",'Minutes'], (0..59) => ["input",'Seconds'],(3600..Float::INFINITY) => ["input/3600",'Hours']}
h.each_pair {|k,v| p "#{v.last} is #{eval(v.first)}" if k.include? input}
```

*Output:*

```
"Hours is 1"
"Minutes is 18"
"Seconds is 14"
```

Comment: This looks fine, but I just want to return either "hours" or "minutes" or "seconds", not the three of them